# In Aqua Data Studio (ADS) can you save queries/open servers without using save all individually?

Tags: sql, aqua-data-studio

After a restart ADS will clear all servers/queries.
There is a save all option but this is not efficient when it must go through often 50+ servers, saving them as separate files.

Essentially I want to reopen my entire workspace on start (all servers and queries I was working on), can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link *may* answer your question...

https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/New-Features-10.0/page/2/5-Autosave-Workspace

Disclaimer: I'm not an active user of AquaData Studio; this is just what I found on a quick search.

Comment: That looks to be it, but think by business has a bat file interfering with that function sadly